# How to handle tf.exe errors in PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, tfs, tf-cli

I have a PowerShell script that run `tf.exe` commands.

```
$tfExe = {C:\path\to\tf.exe}
& $tfExe checkout / checkin etc.
```

If I try to run `checkin` command to file that not changed I got an error:

> The following changes were not checked in because the item were not modified.
>
> Undoing edit: {C:\path\to\file}

The problem is, I run the script within a TFS build, and the build fail with an error:

> [error] There are no remaining changes to check in.

But this is not a real error, if there is no changes so don't do check in, this is good behavior for me.

**How can I handle the `tf.exe` errors?**

I tried with `try catch` but is not worked, altough there is an error the `try` block is excuted and not the `catch`.

I tried also with a variable get the output `$test =  & $tfExe checkin ...` and still get an error (and the variable is empty).

Comment: `$LASTEXITCODE` contains the exit code of the last executable you ran.

Comment: But it doesn't help me becuase I can investigate the `$LASTEXITCODE` only after I already got the error and then the build already failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PowerShell doesn't understand error from native executables. You have to parse through the output to take decision. You can redirect the error stream to output stream.

```
$Output = tf.exe … 2>&1

$Output.exception.message -match 'There are no remaining'
```

Comment: I think it's help me! Thank you!